# Xamarin.Forms - "Target .NET Platform Standard" option not appearing

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xamarin.forms, .net-standard

I'm currently using a PCL in my Xamarin.Forms project and would like to change it to a .NET Standard library. I've looked up tutorials and as far as I understand the first step is to click the "Target .NET Platform Standard" option in the PCL project's properties. The issue is this option is not shown to me, instead, to me, there's a text saying "Learn More" which when clicked takes me to a page comparing .NET Standard to PCL and more https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard#comparison-to-portable-class-libraries. What should I do?

Comment: Create a new .NET Standard library and copy all classes, interfaces, enums etc. into the new library. Best way to go. This converting from pcl to .net standard option did never properly worked for me and caused more problems. we fixed them by creating new .NET Standard libs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did run into the same problem. We tried to convert all our PCLs to .NET Standard. And we thought, that let them "Target .NET Standard" makes them pure .NET Standard libs, but this assumption was wrong. We ran into several problems, untill we realized, that there are some small differences between a PCL Targeting .NET Standard and a pure .NET Standard library.

The Solution was to create new libraries for every PCL and copy the files into the .NET Standard libraries. We are working on .NET Standard 2.0 libs in our Xamarin project now and everything works as expected. Atleast after we updated our VisualStudio to the newest version and after updating resharper to an EAP Release.

So i'd recommend you to go the same way and just create new .NET Standard libraries for your PCL projects and copy the contents.

---

**Additional Information**

*Microsoft.NetCore.CompatibilityPack*

You will run into issues of incopatibility with nuget Packages that do not support .NET Standard yet. You will need [this package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.Portable.Compatibility)

*Channel9 How To*

The following links provides a Channel9 video showing how to migrate to .NET Standard. The guy also talks about the CompatibilityPack and **fallback targets** https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/XamarinShow/Snack-Pack-15-Upgrading-to-XamarinForms-to-NET-Standard